# Xamarin Forms - How to intercept Android app if the app is manually terminated

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin.Forms app runs in the background to track the device's location every 15 seconds or so.

The tracking can be turned on or off by the user via the app.

When the user turns the tracking on, the app issues a local notification on the device stating that tracking is now active.

When the user turns the tracking off, the app clears this local notification.

However, if the app crashes, or is manually terminated by the user, the local notification remains, misleading the user into thinking that tracking is still active.

From within the app, I want to be able to intercept the manual termination of the app so I can clear the local notification, and maybe issue a further notification warning the user that the app was terminated while tracking was active.

I've been able to achieve this very easily within the iOS version of the app by overriding the `AppDelegate.WillTerminate` method.

I've referred to this section of the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle#lifecycle-methods

... but I can't find anything relevant.

I've also tried overriding `Application.CleanUp()` method, but it didn't help.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: local notification? Is it a foreground service notification?

Comment: Not sure what the difference is, tbh.  I am using this library for the local notifications, if that helps... https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification